# How can redirect on my html website youtube embed video to open in youtube application

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, embed

I have youtube embedded videos on my website. When it opens in mobile browser embedded videos open in the default player. I need it to open in youtube application because my videos are 360 degree and it's not working in default browser player.

Comment: This is going to be platform specific.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you provide an example of the solution you've attempted and why exactly it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Youtubes Player API for the IFrame??

> The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your
>   website and control the player using JavaScript. This approach
>   provides more flexibility than the previously available APIs since it
>   allows YouTube to serve an HTML5 player rather than a Flash player for
>   mobile devices that do not support Flash.
>
> Using the API's JavaScript functions, you can queue videos for
>   playback; play, pause, or stop those videos; adjust the player volume;
>   or retrieve information about the video being played. You can also add
>   event listeners that will execute in response to certain player
>   events, such as a player state change or a video playback quality
>   change.

Everything is provided for you.

Link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements